# How can i setup my own SVN

Tags: svn

I am new on SVN how can i setup my own setup SVN. kind give me complete solution form start to end

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask for 'complete solution from start to end'. With that said, you may want to look in the excellent [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) to get started.

Comment: At least specify where you want to setup the repo and on what server/platform. I'm very tempted to -1 because the question is useless and unanswerable in its current form

Answer (score 9):

Go to http://www.visualsvn.com

Download and install the visualsvn server on your server. There is documentation on how to install on that site.

Set up a repository on your server. There is documentation on how to do this on that site.

Set up security for your server and your repository. There is documentation on that site.

Go to http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

Download and install tortoise svn on your client.

Right click on a folder, and go to TortiseSVN->Import

Type in the address of your svn server, and tell it you want to import that folder into the repository you've created.

You are done.

Comment: This is a nice recipe and what I would recommend too if the OP is on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, I think the question could be more clearer. Let me give you a more generic answer and update it as I get more updates on this question.

First and for most you might want to learn about version control concepts. Subversion book would be a good start, checkout http://svnbook.red-bean.com. I would advice you at least check [chapter 4](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.html), which has some useful branching & merging information. If you want to learn about server administration you can look at [Chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.html).

Second, is the server setup. As you have not mentioned the server platform I would suggest [Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/go/csvne2_r2a/). It comes with a wide range of platform support and a good Web UI for administration. BTW, Visual SVN is supported only on windows.

Third, Setup the client side. As like in server even here platform and the tools you are going to use will matter a lot. Let me list few options which comes to my mind TortoiseSVN for just Windows(integrates with windows explorer), Subclipse/subversive a plugin for ecplise (java based multiplatform tool), AnkhSVN and VisualSVN plugins for Visual Studio. There are other plugins

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion requires a server. I've had good results with [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/), which can work with a server if available, but can also comprehensively manage revisions in a local repository with no server administration required.

Supports Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux, with a built-in web server for browsing changesets.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best svn server products is [collabnet subversion edge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/getit.html). I used it long time without problems.

Setup is easy. Follow the instructions here: http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/action/setupcsvn.html