# Code repository running in http port

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to share the html code repository in a server machine and host the source control in http port and not in https or svn ports. A simple code repository with no glitches in setup would be great.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: I tried subversion - svnserve, but its running default on svn and I need it on http port only

Comment: @Bharath http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Comment: It didn't occur to me when answering, but even if research was done, is there a more appropriate Stack Exchange site for hosting software? Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: @ErikGillespie he does not ask about hosted SVN, he asks about SVN server running on plain HTTP. There are several packages that support this.

Comment: I do have Apache Subversion Binary Package installed and working in my pc but by default it runs on svn port
http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

Comment: @bahrep My point was that this is definitely not a *programming* question and I'm wondering if there is another Stack Exchange site where the OP might get more appropriate feedback.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric. Will browse more in Server Fault site for more details. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @ErikGillespie Questions about programming *and* "software tools commonly used by programmers". Source control definitely is part of that. On the other hand, there are probably plenty of questions on this site that are related, but also the svnbook is going to have all of the answers to this (i.e. detailed step by step instructions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue Accessing SVN Repository with Both SVN and HTTP Protocols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385071/issue-accessing-svn-repository-with-both-svn-and-http-protocols)

Comment: Also related: [How can i setup my own SVN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873323/how-can-i-setup-my-own-svn/3873373#3873373)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collabnet subversion edge - http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion

The above said SVN site saved my ass for the day, pretty simple installation and got a Web UI for easy configuration of repositories and user access controls.

Must for Techies who dont have much time to spend creating and hosting a SVN server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP/S-Protocol) over HTTP, it's very easy to setup. :D

Comment: My requirement is to host the repo on http port, but I see GIT was hosted on a different port

Comment: Git is not SVN so you won't have the problem of it trying to run on any SVN ports. The word "Git" in my answer is a link to the exact documentation that describes how to run it over HTTP.

Comment: @Eric: Looking into it

Comment: Also, the instructions get complex to *push* over http - "It’s possible to make Git push over HTTP as well, although that technique isn’t as widely used and requires you to set up complex WebDAV requirements. Because it’s rarely used, we won’t cover it in this book."